# Maven-publish cannot not apply withXML on pom file (No signature of method)

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, maven-publish

Ok, so I am having the exact issue as described here:

[Android library dependencies missing from POM with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827593/android-library-dependencies-missing-from-pom-with-gradle/30523571#30523571)

I copied the provided answer to my gradle file as follows:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId group
            artifactId 'exampleId'
            version version
            artifact source: file('build/outputs/aar/example-release.aar')

            //The publication doesn't know about our dependencies, so we have to manually add them to the pom
            pom.withXml {
                // for dependencies and exclusions
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { ModuleDependency dp ->
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dp.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dp.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dp.version)

                    // for exclusions
                    if (dp.excludeRules.size() > 0) {
                        def exclusions = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
                        dp.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule ex ->
                            def exclusion = exclusions.appendNode('exclusion')
                            exclusion.appendNode('groupId', ex.group)
                            exclusion.appendNode('artifactId', ex.module)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url  selectDeploymentURL()
            if ( project.hasProperty( 'nexusUser' ) ) {
                credentials {
                    username project.getProperty('nexusUser')
                    password project.getProperty('password')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting an error when attempting to publishToMavenLocal, and I'm not sure why?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'path/build.gradle' line: 136

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':example:generatePomFileForMavenAarPublication'.
        > Could not apply withXml() to generated POM
> No signature of method: build_42xq5bsii69isvukzktk1oy51$_run_closure5_closure19_closure21_closure23_closure24.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency_Decorated) values: [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency_Decorated@433edba9]
Possible solutions: doCall(org.gradle.api.artifacts.ModuleDependency), findAll(), findAll(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)
```

Note: Line 136 is this line:

```
configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { ModuleDependency dp ->
```

Comment: Replace `compile` with `implementation` or `api`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So as Karma has it, I found the answer shortly after posting

I just removed the ModuleDependency dp and referred to everything from it, and it got past this error, I see the new nodes in the pom file now.

```
configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
```

Comment: what did you mean by the dp?

Comment: what is  'it', it.name,it.version

Answer (score 2):

Compile is deprecated we have to use implementation.

for Example

```
 configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                if(it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified".equals(it.name)) && it.version != null)
                {
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the crash is that not all dependencies are `ModuleDependency` objects. Something like the following should fix the problem and lets you still add exclusions (which aren't on the base class).

```
configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { dp ->
    if (dp instanceof ModuleDependency) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```