# including dependencies in generated pom of android library

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, artifactory

I'm trying to publish an Android library to a local JFrog Artifactory. Currently I have this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId libraryGroupId
            version libraryVersion
            artifactId libraryArtifactId

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/app-beta-debug.aar")
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'

            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        defaults {
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true

            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'q.os': 'android', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

I have skipped some parts like android and dependencies sections for brevity. The build.gradle has multiple compile dependencies.

```
gradle artifactoryPublish
```

published the artifact to Artifactory but the generated pom doesn't have the dependencies. I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30523571/2829308

from this answer, `pom.withXml` worked (although I couldn't figure out how to exclude a dependency). But this seems hackish. I feel like there should be a better way available. I tried using the `uploadArchives` way as follows

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local")
            pom.version = libraryVersion
            pom.artifactId = libraryArtifactId
            pom.groupId = libraryGroupId
        }
    }
}
```

It says task successful but artifact doesn't get published in Artifactory. Am I missing something obvious? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pom file shouldn't include transitive dependencies, only direct ones. Maven parses the pom files to find direct dependencies, download them and continue from there in a recursive manner.

The only dependencies that you should see in your pom file are the ones declared in the `dependences` block of your gradle script.

Comment: I think that's what he's saying.  The library project has dependencies and they aren't included in his pom.  I'm having the same issue unless I do that hack.