# Skipping upload for missing aar and pom file

Tags: android, maven, gradle, pom.xml, android-library

I'm building an `aar` Library for Android and im facing an issue. POM and ARR files are not uploaded.

There is a error

> Skipping upload for missing file 'F:\Android\Personal_Project\sampleMavenLib\sinalib\build\outputs\aar\sinalib-release.aar'.
>   Skipping upload for missing file 'F:\Android\Personal_Project\sampleMavenLib\sinalib\build\publications\Production\pom-default.xml'.

I checked these two path and the aar file was there and its generated but there isnt any path for pom file

this is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.2"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    }
}

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'sinalib'

    publishedGroupId = 'come.sinarahimi.sinalib'
    libraryName = 'Sinalib'
    artifact = 'sinalib'

libraryDescription = 'This view is a container that supports diagonal scroll and fling gesture. It is based on AOSP HorizontalScrollView.'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/Sinarahimi/sampleMavenLib'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/Sinarahimi/sampleMavenLib.git'

libraryVersion = '1.0.2'

developerId = 'sinarahimi'
developerName = 'Sina RAHIMI'
developerEmail = 'develop.rahimi95@gmail.com'

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
```

}

```
publishing {
    publications {
        Production(MavenPublication) {
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/sinalib-release.aar")
            groupId publishedGroupId
            artifactId artifact
            version libraryVersion

            //The publication doesn't know about our dependencies, so we have to manually add them to the pom
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    bintray {
        // Get Bintray credential from environment variable

        Properties properties = new Properties()
 properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStrea( 
        ))
        user = properties.getProperty('user')
        key = properties.getProperty('apikey')
        override = true
        pkg {
            repo = bintrayRepo
            name = project.name
            userOrg = 'sinara'
            licenses = allLicenses
            desc = libraryDescription
            websiteUrl = siteUrl
            vcsUrl = gitUrl
            version {
                name = libraryVersion
            }
            publish = true
        }
        publications = ['Production']
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried a lot of things i found two points :

1 - i changed this

```
artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/sinalib-release.aar")
```

to

```
artifact("build/outputs/aar/sinalib-release.aar")
```

2 - The repository that you create in  [bintray.com](https://bintray.com) should be the same as the repo in the `pkg` part.

this solved the Error `Skipping upload for missing file` and it uploaded the arr file.
But One error still remains that it cant upload and generate `pom` file.

So i found this command:

```
clean build generatePomFileForProductionPublication bintrayUpload
```

It was working for me but still, have a problem with adding dependencies into pom 
although I have this code it doesn't work :

```
//The publication doesn't know about our dependencies, so we have to manually add them to the pom
        pom.withXml {
            def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

            //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
            configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

try generatePomFileForReleasePublication or publishReleasePublicationToMavenLocal.

The full commend is:

```
./gradlew clean build generatePomFileForReleasePublicationbintrayUpload -PbintrayUser=<BINTRAY_USER> -PbintrayKey=<BINTRAY_KEY> -PdryRun=false
```

Comment: i get error 
' Task 'generatePomFileForReleasePublicationbintrayUpload' not found in project ':sinalib'.'

Comment: Do you give BINTRAY_USER and key properly??

Comment: Yes, But its said that there is no task  like 'generatePomFileForReleasePublicationbintrayUpload'

Comment: Another solutions for POM missing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827593/android-library-dependencies-missing-from-pom-with-gradle?rq=1

Comment: Where is pom file exactly go when it's uploaded?